# Functions using global values and race condition

Tags: java, variables

```
 class {
     public static int ID = 1000;
     public static int A = 1;
     public void onDestroyed(World world, int x, int y, int z, int m) {
         ID = 1000;
         A = 1;
         //Some stuff that will generate X;
         while (X > 0) {
             //Scanning through arrays to find proper ID (it will lower X by some value until it find good ID)
             X = X - ChanceList.get(i - 1);
             ID = DropList.get(i - 1);
             --i;
         }
         if (ID != 1000) //ID has changed
         {
             world.set(x, y, z, ID, 0, 2);
             A = 0;
         }
     }
     public int quantityDropped(Random par1Random) //This is called by world.set, after onDestroyed() is done
     {
         return A;
     }
 }
```

**Short:** ID = 1000 => onDestroyed() => if(ID has changed) A = 0, if (ID is the same) A = 1; => quantityDropped() => return 1 or 0 depending on global A.

**Question:** If this class (functions) is called many of times (approx: 10 times a sec) and operation defined as: "Scanning through arrays" weights no more than 1000 increments.

Can I get a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes race conditions are possible(Assuming it is multi-threaded) but the number of race-condition based bugs will very depending on how often you set and reference ID and A. For production coding you should probably fix that, for any other use you might be able to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run into a race condition with this code, as Static variables in a class are shared by all objects instantiated from that same Class.

So if you have ObjectA and ObjectB both derived from the same Class existing simultaneously, and ObjectA sets "ID" to "123" then ObjectB.ID will also now equal 123.  If ObjectB wasn't expecting ID to change like that, then it can cause a race condition, or (other) unexpected errors.

This problem can/will become magnified dramatically in the case of multi-threading.